# Missing options in DirectOptions class

Tags: java, apache-beam, direct-runner

The [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/) mention the following options:
`direct_num_workers` and `direct_running_mode` as well as setting the `streaming` option.

All of these are missing from the [DirectOptions class](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.24.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/runners/direct/DirectOptions.html)

Also when trying to set those from `args` the following exception is thrown:

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class interface org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectOptions missing a property named 'direct_running_mode'.
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.parseObjects(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1613)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.access$400(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Builder.as(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:300)
```

Has someone managed to use these? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These options are relevant for the Python SDK only, it’s actually not clear as these options are documented in the caveats section for both sdks, it should be hidden when documenting the Java SDK, feel free to report the documentation issue.

These options are part of the Python [FnApiRunner](https://beam.apache.org/contribute/runner-guide/#the-fn-api).